# Retrieve image from HTTP response body

Tags: image, http, go, get

I am trying to retrieve an image from a Server via an HTTP GET request in my Client service.
I reproduced my use case in the following code:

main.go:

```
package main

import (
    "net/http"
    "os"

    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    log "github.com/sirupsen/logrus"
)

func main() {
    log.SetFormatter(&log.TextFormatter{})

    // Initialize router
    router := mux.NewRouter()

    args := os.Args

    if args[1] == "client" {
        log.Print("Run Client, listening on port 8080")
        router.Methods("GET").Path("/image").HandlerFunc(ClientGetImage)
        log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", router))
    } else if args[1] == "server" {
        log.Print("Run Server, listening on port 4242")
        router.Methods("GET").Path("/image").HandlerFunc(ServerGetImage)
        log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":4242", router))
    } else {
        log.Fatal("Wrong command. Choose [client] or [server] option")
    }
}
```

client.go:

```
package main

import (
    "image"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func ClientGetImage(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    // Make HTTP Get request to retrieve the image from the server
    log.Print("Requesting image to server")
    resp, err := http.Get("http://localhost:4242/image")

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    m, _, err := image.Decode(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    log.Print("Pixels: ", m)
}
```

server.go:

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "image"
    "image/color"
    "image/jpeg"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "strconv"
)

func ServerGetImage(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    img := image.NewGray16(image.Rect(0, 0, 1, 1))
    img.SetGray16(0, 0, color.Gray16{Y: 42000})

    // Print created
    log.Print("Pixels: ", img)

    buffer := new(bytes.Buffer)
    if err := jpeg.Encode(buffer, img, nil); err != nil {
        log.Println("unable to encode image.")
    }

    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "image/jpeg")
    w.Header().Set("Content-Length", strconv.Itoa(len(buffer.Bytes())))
    if _, err := w.Write(buffer.Bytes()); err != nil {
        log.Println("unable to write image.")
    }
}
```

The purpose is pretty simple: upon reception of a GET request, the client sends a GET request to the server to retrieve an image.
Upon reception of the Client's GET request, the server creates a 1x1 image, encoded in 16bits.

After running my client and server, when I send a my GET request to the client, I get the following logs:

Server logs:

```
INFO[0000] Run Server, listening on port 4242           
2019/09/30 15:32:05 Pixels: &{[164 16] 2 (0,0)-(1,1)}
```

Client logs:

```
INFO[0000] Run Client, listening on port 8080           
2019/09/30 15:41:52 Requesting image to server
2019/09/30 15:41:52 Pixels: &{[164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164
 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 1
64 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164
 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 1
64 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164
 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 1
64 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164
 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 1
64 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164
 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 1
64 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164
 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164 164] [128 128 128 128 128 128
 128 128 128 128 128 128 128 128 128 128 128 128 128 128 128 128 128 128 128 128 128 128 1
28 128 128 128 128 128 128 128 128 128 128 128 128 128 128 128 128 128 128 128 128 128 128
 128 128 128 128 128 128 128 128 128 128 128 128 128] [128 128 128 128 128 128 128 128 128 128 128 128 128 128 128 128 128 128 128 128 128 128 128 128 128 128 128 128 128 128 128 128 128 128 128 128 128 128 128 128 128 128 128 128 128 128 128 128 128 128 128 128 128 128 128 128 128 128 128 128 128 128 128 128] 16 8 YCbCrSubsampleRatio420 (0,0)-(1,1)}
```

I was expecting that the client would print:
Pixels: &{[164 16] 2 (0,0)-(1,1)} 
as well. 
Is it just a difference in the printing format, or is the image not-correctly decoded?

Comment: I don't see any error output here. What exactly is the problem?

Comment: "my client can't decode correctly the image sent" meaning what? Decode it into what? What are you trying to do with it?

Comment: I don't understand why the output printed is different in the client and in the server. Or perhaps it's just a different format, but I was expecting the client to write: "Pixels: &{[164 16] 2 (0,0)-(1,1)}" as well

Comment: The encoded image is a image.Gray16. The decoded  image is a image.YCbCr. These images types have different representations and therefore print differently.  Decode from JPEG will always return a image.YCbCr.

Comment: In server.go `img` is of type `image.Gray16` and in client.go `m` is of type `image.Image`. Different things will be printed differently. If new to Go: Take the Tour of Go and focus on the interface types.

Comment: Note that this is totally **unrelated** to HTTP and all that complication.

Comment: "I am trying to send an image between a Client and a Server via an HTTP GET request" -- this is not possible. To send an image from client to server you must use POST or PUT, because a GET request has no body.

Comment: @Flimzy  The prose in the question can be more clear about the direction of the request, but the code clearly shows that the client is getting the image from the server.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Cerise Limon, I didn't know that decoded image was a YCbCr.
If I try to convert to a Gray16 image, it gives me the expected output format.
Much clearer now!

Indeed this was not related to HTTP.. I wrote a simpler piece of code:

```
    // Create a 2x1 Gray16 image
    img := image.NewGray16(image.Rect(0, 0, 2, 1))
    // Set 1st pixel to 42
    img.SetGray16(0, 0, color.Gray16{Y: 42})

    log.Print("Pixels: ", img)

    // Encode the image
    buffer := new(bytes.Buffer)
    jpeg.Encode(buffer, img, &jpeg.Options{Quality: 100})

    // Decode the encoded buffer
    m, _ := jpeg.Decode(buffer)

    // Create a Gray16 image and fill it with decoded image
    newImage := image.NewGray16(image.Rect(0, 0, m.Bounds().Dx(), m.Bounds().Dy()))
    draw.Draw(newImage, newImage.Bounds(), m, m.Bounds().Min, draw.Src)

    log.Print("Pixels: ", newImage)
```

This gives me the following output:

```
INFO[0000] Pixels: &{[0 42 0 0] 4 (0,0)-(2,1)}          
INFO[0000] Pixels: &{[0 0 0 0] 4 (0,0)-(2,1)}
```

Note that if I replace Gray16 by Gray, the encoding/decoding seems to work correctly: i get the same image in output than the input one.

Am I missing something here? 
Thanks!